# Server-Side JS in ASP implications

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, global-variables, environment-variables, server-side

I was trying to use JavaScript as a scripting language in a classic-ASP website.
I came across several errors. Many JS objects would not work and also some constants. Can someone explain the implications of using JavaScript as a server-side scripting language. This is my first attempt at a JavaScript powered asp website, so I have provided this code.

```
<%
var user = Request.QueryString("name");
Response.Cookies("thisUser") = user;

var expdate = new Date(Date.now().setMinutes(Date.now().getMinutes()+5));
Response.Cookies("thisUser").Expires = expdate.toString();

function _greet(name) {
    Response.Write("<p>And also you... <b>" + name + "</b> ...I guess...</p>");
}

%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>ASP</title></head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("<p>Hello World!</p>");
if (user != undefined) {
    _greet(user);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

`_greet()` always runs regardless of whether `user` is undefined. `expdate.toString()` causes internal server error due to not returning a string of date type. It just returns the number and `toDateString()` is not supported! And is there any way to debug JavaScript in ASP?

P.S. I already set the default language to JavaScript in the server manager(IIS 8.5). Also I am just testing as an intranet site.

Comment: I've seen my problems work in other web pages. Maybe I'm missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking to see if the cookie is being set, you have to read the cookie and check if it really expires in the set 5 minutes.

The `.Expires` setting seems to expect the date formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd H:m` format.(I am not sure if this is the ONLY format it accepts, you could try different variations)

```
<%@ Language= "JavaScript" %> 
<%

var user = Request.QueryString("name");

//set the cookie only if it is not undefined
if(user+"" != "undefined")
{
    //write the name to cookie
    Response.Cookies("thisUser") = user;

    var fiveMinutesLater = new Date();
    fiveMinutesLater.setMinutes(fiveMinutesLater.getMinutes() + 5);

    //Response.Cookies("thisUser").Expires seems to expect the date in yyyy-MM-dd H:m format
    var formatteddate= fiveMinutesLater.getFullYear()+ "-" +("0" + (fiveMinutesLater.getMonth()+ 1)).slice(-2)+ "-" + ("0" + fiveMinutesLater.getDate()).slice(-2)+ " " + ("0" + fiveMinutesLater.getHours()).slice(-2)+":"+("0" + fiveMinutesLater.getMinutes()).slice(-2)

    Response.Cookies("thisUser").Expires = formatteddate;   
}


function _greet(name) {
    Response.Write("<p>And also you... <b>" + name + "</b> ...I guess...</p>");
}
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>ASP</title></head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("<p>Hello World!</p>");

//Read the cookie.
var thisUser = Request.Cookies("thisUser");

if (thisUser != "") {
    _greet(thisUser);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is `undefined` not recognized?

Comment: Also when I viewed the expiry date on the browser console it was in GMT. Is this normal? But it is system locale time in the script.

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable `user` will never be undefined in your `if` block, since you define it here:

```
var user = Request.QueryString("name");
```

It might be null or empty string, but not undefined. So just perform such check instead:

```
if ((user + "").length > 0) {
    _greet(user);
}
```

This will check the length, and only when something is there will execute the function.

---

Second, the `.Expires` property of a Cookie instance should get a date anyway, not a string. Just remove the `.toString()` call and it should work:

```
Response.Cookies("thisUser").Expires = expdate;
```

Comment: I tried it the very first time and it didn't work. I also tried formatting with `toDateString()` and `toUTCString()`, but those didn't work either.